# Hibernate ORM Native Query to Json Objects with keys

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus

**Background**

I have Maven with Hibernate set up to the point where I can

```
@GET
@Path("/test")
@Transactional
public Response test() {
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * from some_table");
    List<Object[]> result = query.getResultList();
    return Response.ok(result).build();
}
```

**Current result**

The result I get right now is

```
[
    [1, "Something", "Something else"],
    [2, "Another", "Anotherother"],
    ...
]
```

**Desired result**

This is almost what I want, except I would like each row to be a Json Object with keys that correspond to the column name. I.e.

```
[
    {"id": 1, "name": "Something", "description": "Something else"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Another", "description": "Anotherother"},
    ...
]
```

**Question**

As far as I can tell, the result I get is because I retrieve the result as `List<Object[]>` from the `.getResultList()` method. Presumably I have to fetch it as a `List<Map<String, Object>>` in some way.

Am I on the right track here, or do I need to reconsider the entire approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data transformation can be done using a [ResultTransformer](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/transform/ResultTransformer.html).

```
List<JsonObject> l = query.unwrap(org.hibernate.Query.class).setResultTransformer(JsonRT.INSTANCE);

class JsonRT implements ResultTransformer {
  public static final JsonRT INSTANCE = new JsonRT();

  public Object transformTuple(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases) {
    final JsonObject o = new JsonObject();
    /* populate object with key/value pair */
    return o;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is an OR-mapper but you are not really using it's OR-features. If all you want is to produce JSON from a table, you should use whatever function your database offers for aggregating a row to a JSON array of JSON objects. In PostgreSQL you could use `select json_agg(row_to_json(t)) from some_table t`

Comment: This is only true if you are returning right away that value, otherwise you are just returning JSON in order to be transformed, worked on, and then returned back (as JSON or any other format)...quite expensive I would say. Additionally, if you ever need to tweak the response you would need different queries (not a show-stopper for small applications). On the other hand, keep in mind you are putting another approach in between.

Comment: I was just trying to give the OP a minimal solution. He can of course introduce DTOs and do some kind of mapping, but he could just as well adapt the query.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that you need to use a DTO pattern.

That way, you can push to Jackson a proper object that will be serialized with property names and values.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Use DTO**

or

**2. Use 2D HashMap with this**

```
   for(Object[] obj : objects){
       store(obj[1]);
   }
```